# Where is LiveCD Ubuntu saving the downloaded files?

Tags: live-cd

I wanted to wipe my hard drive, so I looked at the output of `fdisk -l` and run the following two commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

I thought `sdb` had something to do with my previous installation, but then I realized that it was my USB drive and that I had just wiped my Ubuntu LiveUSB.

Now I have a 32-bit LiveCD and I am downloading the 64-bit ISO.

My question is: is the 64-bit iso actually being downloaded, and where exactly? My hard drive is unformatted. I am using a browser download. Is it storing the ISO on RAM? Will I be able to make a bootstick with it in LiveCD? Because I made the CD on Windows and I doubt that the LiveCD treats the CD as storage item.

Comment: You will be able to access it in the downloads folder

Answer (score 1):

I found out that LiveCD stores all the data gathered on RAM and if one runs out RAM, then it spills it over to the installation device itself if it has been modified for any spare room.